# Startup.cs error on AddDBContext Value must not be null

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get my connection to a Database to work in .NET Core using Entity Framework. The Models and Context was constructed via DB first approach.

In my startup i have the following lines of code:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. 
////Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<PersonalProfileContext>(options => options
      .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

In my context, i have the following:

```
public virtual DbSet<Companies> Companies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Qualifications> Qualifications { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<RolesCompanies> RolesCompanies { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<RolesUsers> RolesUsers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

public  PersonalProfileContext(DbContextOptions<PersonalProfileContext> options) 
    : base(options)
{
    return;
}
```

In the startup.cs i get an error saying Value must not be null on the AddDBContext line.

In my appsettings.json file it is the following:

```
 {
  "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "" <-- Not included for safety reasons
  },

  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "" <-- Not included for security reasons
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: My immediate thought is does `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")` return the correct value? My assumption is that the value of of the connection string is either coming back null, empty, or is pointing at a database which doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamieTaylor It does return null but I'm not sure why when i have DefaultConnection in the AppSettings.json file

Comment: So your problem is that the connection string isn't being accessed from your `appsettings.json` file. Is it possible to share a redacted version of it?

Comment: @JamieTaylor please see the edit to my questions :)

Comment: Ah. You're `appsettings.json` is slightly malformed. Check my [appsettings in pone of my projects](https://github.com/GaProgMan/dwCheckApi/blob/master/dwCheckApi/appsettings.Production.json#L2)

Comment: Change around the words `"DefaultConnection"` and `"ConnectionString"` and make it `ConnectionStrings` (plural)

Comment: It won't format nicely, but this is what you're aiming for: `"ConnectionStrings": { "DefaultConnection": <connection string goes here> }`

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks everyone!

Comment: I've posted the solution as an answer (mostly so that folks in the future can see what the solution was). @UncountedBrute, could you mark it as the accepted answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the connection strings section of your appsettings.json is not quite right.

The following is what you have supplied:

```
"DefaultConnection": {
     "ConnectionString": "" <-- Not included for safety reasons
 }
```

Whereas what you need it to be is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
     "DefaultConnection": "" <-- Not included for safety reasons
}
```

This caused the following line to fail:

```
services.AddDbContext<PersonalProfileContext>(options => options
  .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

As there was no connection string in the `ConnectionStrings` collection called `DefaultConnection`, this:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```

returns `null`, which means this:

```
options
  .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

returns `null`, meaning that `null` was being passed into the call to `AddDbContext`.

It's an easy mistake to make, and not an easy one to spot.